# Webview in recyclerview

Tags: webview, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling

I have a list of webview to show different pdf's, I need to show it in a horizontal RecyclerView, but the problem is that when I scroll it horizontally then the coming webview just goes on top of the current one and the current one instead of shifting to the left hand side, it remains at its position. It looks a little weird.

This is my RecyclerViewAdapter

public class HorizontalManual extends RecyclerView
        .Adapter {

```
Context context;
private ArrayList<String> list;

public class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imgUploaded;ProgressBar loader; WebView webViewManual;

    public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        webViewManual = (WebView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pdf_manual_webView);
    }
}


public HorizontalManual(Context context, ArrayList<String> list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}


@Override
public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {

    View view = null;
    try {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.horz_pdf, parent, false);
        if (view.getLayoutParams ().width == RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
            view.getLayoutParams ().width = parent.getWidth ();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new DataObjectHolder(view);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final DataObjectHolder holder, final int position) {

    String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + list.get(position);
    Log.e("pdf",url);
    WebSettings websettings = holder.webViewManual.getSettings();
    websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    holder.webViewManual.loadUrl(url);

    holder.webViewManual.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            holder.webViewManual.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "document.getElementsByClassName('ndfHFb-c4YZDc-GSQQnc-LgbsSe ndfHFb-c4YZDc-to915-LgbsSe VIpgJd-TzA9Ye-eEGnhe ndfHFb-c4YZDc-LgbsSe')[0].style.display='none'; })()");
        }
    });
    holder.webViewManual.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    holder.webViewManual.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}
```

}

I'm setting the HorizontalList in my Fragment like this:

```
mRecyclerViewManual.setHasFixedSize(true);
rLayoutManagerManual = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);                    mRecyclerViewManual.setLayoutManager(rLayoutManagerManual);
//Setting adapter
HorizontalManual setUploadsListAdapterManual = new HorizontalManual(context, list);                    mRecyclerViewManual.setAdapter(setUploadsListAdapterManual);
```

Comment: Please post your code here@Syed

Comment: @CrazyAndroid, here is the code of my RecyclerViewAdapter named as HorizontalManual

Comment: Where are you setting the DataObjectHolder in your Activity,please show it.@Syed

Comment: @CrazyAndroid I'm setting the HroizontalManual which is the name of my recyclerviewadapter in my fragment.

Comment: Ok then please post it,how did you set it in your fragment@Syed

Comment: I have posted it. @CrazyAndroid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Load you google doc url using iframe tag as shown below.

 String frameVideo = "<html><body>Youtube video .. <br> <iframe width=\"320\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://Dealerapp.ebunch.ca/upload/wl/manuals/7.pdf\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";

        holder.webView.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
```